# Is there a strategy for using the Position Buttons?

Tags: bloons-td-5

In Bloons TD 5, almost every tower has these following buttons: [image]

I know what they do, but I want to know what towers I can use them on to have **maximum** popping.

Comment: related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/206921/is-targeting-closest-or-last-ever-useful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Which to choose strongly depends on which tower you're using.

- For towers that does large damage to small number of targets, like snipers and anti-MOAB towers, you want to target **strong**, since that will ensure the shot is not wasted
- For towers dealing Area of Effect damage, you want to target **close** or **last**, since that is usually where the largest concentration of enemies are
- For towers with slow moving shots, using **close** will ensure the shots do not miss
- For towers firing in a straight line, like the Spike-o-pult, placing them at the end of a long straight path and choosing **last** will ensure maximum damage
- Single target towers like the Super Monkey or towers at the end that are used to sweep up bloons can be left on **first** to ensure nothing gets through

There are many ways to combine the effect of multiple towers with these to maximize effects. Of course these only come into play once you're some levels into the game. Earlier on all towers can be left on first with little effect.